# Metabox not being added

Tags: metabox

what is wrong with my code ? why it doesnt add meta box ?

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'clivern_plugin_top_menu');

function clivern_plugin_top_menu() {

    add_menu_page('My Custom Page', 'My Custom Page', 'manage_options', 'my-top-level-slug', 'clivern_plugin_top');
}

function clivern_plugin_top() {
    add_meta_box('custom-page', 'Custom Page', 'show_custom_page_metabox');
    do_meta_boxes('my-top-level-slug', 'normal', 'saed');
}

function show_custom_page_metabox() {
    echo "asd";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code doesn't call the metaboxes of the good screen.

Try this to call the metaboxes of the current screen.

```
do_meta_boxes('', 'normal', 'saed');
```